# Form layout in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to create tableless Form using  and  tags, im stuck.

I want the form look like this:

[image]

I should be able to set the width of textbox, text area and select in CSS.

Comment: What's your current code? You can share it via jsfiddle.net

Comment: See jsfiddle.net/Xh5aL/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make each row a `<p>` containing a `<label>` and an `<input>`, both `display: inline-block` with preset width.  (The `<label>` should be `text-align: right`)

The buttons can be `float: right`.

Comment: I don't like <p>, I prefer ul

Comment: @user: So what?  You can do the exact same thing.

Comment: @user: Your elements are too wide to fit in the `<ul>`, so they're line-wrapping.  Also, the `<li>`s shouldn't be `inline-block`.  http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/Xh5aL/4/

Answer (score 1):

check out working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bRm3P/2/

```
<form>
<label>To: <input type="text" /></label>
<label>Subject: <input type="text" /></label>
<label>Message: <textarea></textarea></label>  
<div class="submit-container">    
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/><input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
</form>

<style>
form {
    width: 500px;
}

label {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

label input,label textarea {
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    width: 80%;
    vertical-align: top;
}


.submit-container {
    padding-top: 4px;
    text-align: right;
}
</style>
```

Comment: While this is, pretty much, how I'd do it, I'll draw your attention to the top-aligned `label` + `textarea` combo in his demo picture (bottom-aligned in your demo). :)

Comment: i guess that will be an exercise for the poster :) or here http://jsfiddle.net/bRm3P/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is a good walk through: http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/06/clean-and-pure-css-form-design.html

Answer (score 0):

A nice semantic layout would be one of the following:

```
<ul>
  <li><label>To <input></label></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Or with a dl (more common):

```
<dl>
   <dt><label>To</label></dt><dd><input></dd>
   ...
</dl>
```

You will find lots of ways to layout the latter if you google for: definition list layout form